# I resigned and took another position in the same organization. Was called insubordinate

Tags: resignation, internal-transfer

I am a school employee and was given notice of involuntary transfer to another building.  I replied that I would be resigning and substituting instead.  I did so the following day, with my resignation effective the day before I was to start at the new location.  I am being told that saying and doing this was insubordination as I refused to comply with directions.  There is no claim that I was rude, loud, used inappropriate language, etc.

Comment: I'm *presuming* the question being asked here is if you were insubordinate. In which case the answer is 'no' - they wanted you to work somewhere you didn't want to work and you resigned. That's not insubordination.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You declined to subordinate your needs to those of your employer, and found another employer. Technically that could be called insubordination, but why do you care what it's called?

Comment: If you are not working there anymore, then why the angst ?

Comment: @RohitGupta feedback and course correction, as needed, maybe? In case you're not sure, it's better to ask!

Answer (score 7):

Insubordination broadly, is not following your employers directions **when you would be obliged to do so**.

If you have an employment contract or some mandatory notice period in effect, that indicates that you remain employed for that day, then yes, you were insubordinate.

Otherwise, if you were indeed free to resign, then you were not employed, and thus not obliged to follow your employer's directions.

Insubordination has nothing to do with being rude, loud, or any other negative way of communicating.

Answer (score 4):

Insubordination requires that the person making such claim actually has the authority to make orders related to the subject.

The person you've mentioned could not order you to not resign.  Actually, no one has that authority!  What you did was actually pretty crafty, but not illegal or immoral.  I have teacher friends who don't want to put up with school politics, and thus prefer being substitute teachers.  You just happened to deal with someone who didn't expect you to exercise your authority to bail out, and "insubordination" was the best word they could use to try to shame you for your actions.